# Using a shell script to add a ‘</pre>’ after the last line in a large file

Tags: sed, awk

I need a SED, or AWK, command to find the last line in a file, and add `</pre>` to it.

Such as:

```
LINELINELINE
```

Changes to:

```
LINELINELINE</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use what is known as a **compound command.** That's a list of commands, which the shell treats as a single command for the purpose of anything external to the compound command.

Yes, that's somewhat of a recursive definition; an example makes it easier to understand.

For example, to surround a file with `<pre>` and `</pre>`, you might use a command like:

```
( printf '<pre>' ; cat originalfile ; printf '</pre>' ) > newfile
```

If you don't have a temporary file, but rather want to surround the output of some command with something else, you can inject that command instead of the `cat`:

```
( printf '<pre>' ; find / -type d -print ; printf '</pre>' ) > somefile
```

This all works by applying the redirection to the output of the whole compound command, instead of just its parts.

Of course, this doesn't use `sed` or `awk` as requested, but for this sort of task, going to those tools is quite overkill.

Comment: This may work better for one-lining and simplicity, and the fact that I have a temp file would work better for this. I am going to try it, and then see results.

Comment: This worked better, for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
echo "</pre>" >> /path/to/the/file
```

Or at the beginning is a bit trickier, you'd need to use a different file for the output.

```
echo "<pre>" | cat - /path/to/the/file > /path/to/the/newfile
```

`cat` means concatenate, and it has two arguments in this case: the `-` means stdin, so the first part of the concatenated file is whatever is piped to it (in this case the `echo`).  The second argument is the file you want to prepend to.  The concatenated files are then output to `newfile`.

Comment: I just thought of something like that, thanks. Didn't know it was that simple.

Comment: Is there a way to do this to the beginning of the file? Since this seems to be the simpler (more readable) way than using sed.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Useless use of `echo`? :-) `cat <<<'<pre>' - /path/to/the/file` Of course, that becomes rather more complicated if you want more than one string either at the beginning or the end.

Comment: The `echo` isn't "useless", it is outputting the string.  There may be alternative ways of doing this, but the absence of the command "echo" in this method would result in an error.  I like your approach though.  Aside form the useless use of `printf` where `echo` would suffice :) upvoted.

Comment: @Paul At least I didn't use a format string for `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

With (GNU) `sed` (as per the tag in the question):

```
$ sed -i -e '$a\</pre>' file.in
```

This will *add* a line with `</pre>` on it to `file.in`.

Alternatively:

```
$ sed -i -e '$s@\(.*\)@\1</pre>@' file.in
```

This will add `</pre>` to the last line in `file.in`.